# AWS Ruby SDK - Delete application and all associated environments

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the AWS Ruby SDK to interact with Amazon Beanstalk. I've got applications with more or more running environments. The application names are easily known to my Ruby code, but the environment names were dynamically generated, and so aren't easily obtainable.

I hoped that the delete_application method would also terminate all running environments automatically, but the following error results from trying to delete a Beanstalk application with running environments:

```
Unable to delete application dsw88-test-app-prod because it has a version that is deployed to a running environment.
```

Deleting an application manually in the AWS console also is able to automatically remove running environments. Is there a way to easily delete an application and all its running environments using the Ruby SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I don't believe this is possible. Instead, you must use the following process:

1. Get a list of all the environments in your application using the describe_environments call
2. Terminate each one of those running environments using the terminate_environment call
3. Once those are done (You should wait for them to finish), then you can run the delete_application call to delete your application

It would be nice if Amazon provided a way to delete all that stuff programmatically with one command (like they do in the UI), but it doesn't look like that is currently supported.